# Refresh Pivot Table with XLWINGS

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I am trying to refresh a pivot table in excel upon data written by XLWINGS.
As I don't know how to do it directly from XLWINGS, I tried to use VBA.

Let's split my process in 2 steps:

Step1

I launch the python code from vba (my module name is "PosRep", the python code writtes back a range of data in a specified sheet thanks to xlwings.

```
Sub launchPython()
RunPython ("import PosRep; PosRep")
End Sub
```

Step 2

But as I don't know in advance the size of my newly created Range in Excel, I want to select it, add a new Name (NamedRange) and refresh my pivot (already linked to the NamedRange).

```
Sub SelectRange()
Worksheets("GPODump").Range("A1").Select
'...
End Sub
```

Both Subs work independently well. But I cannot manage to make them work in a raw. The following code:

```
Sub Main()
launchPython
SelectRange
End Sub
```

produces a VBA error "Select method of Range class failed" on the statement:

```
Worksheets("GPODump").Range("A1").Select
```

I presume there is a conflict with the XLWINGS VBA module but I can't figure out what it can be...
Anyone's help would be more than welcome !
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late but you can do it within xlwings - this is what worked for me:

```
import xlwings as xw
# open excel App
app_excel = xw.App(visible = False)
# open the excel file, select the tab and the PivotTable to refresh
wbook = xw.Book( 'YourFile.xlsx' )
wbook.sheets['Tab1'].select()
wbook.api.ActiveSheet.PivotTables('PivotTableName').PivotCache().refresh()
```

Comment: Unkown property, element or command: "ActiveSheet". Any help?

Comment: @FelipeMaion in MacOS it seems that the `api` objects are in camel case. Try `wb.api.active_sheet`

Comment: @N4v Yeap, I've found out reading the github here: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/master/resources/mac/mac_dict_1642.py

Comment: Refresh() not refresh() worked for me - everything else as described. THANKS! It is never too late...

Comment: When running this all in a script, I also needed to activate the workbook before selecting the sheet with: wbook.activate()

Comment: @DrWhat, i guess they've changed the package since i last used that piece of code. I didn't have to use xlwings that much since 2019

Answer (score 2):

I was looking how to solve this for Mac, here is how I did to refresh all pivot tables and etc:

```
wb.api.active_sheet.refresh_all(wb.api)
```

Hopes that this saves someone else time. Took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: To wait for the refresh to complete for External Data Ranges, Enable Background Refresh needs to be disabled in the properties. I hope this also saves some more time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the VBA code. The following code works fine:

```
Sheets("GPODump").Select
Sheets("GPODump").Range("A1").Select
```